# How to set default workspace for project in TFS 2012/VS2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs, source-control-explorer

I am working on 2 projects connected to the same TFS catalog (one for main work and second for quick fixes/tests). The problem is that whenever I change a project I need to switch workspace in the Source Control Explorer. It is quite annoying and often I click "get latest version" but nothing is being updated cause the Workspace from pevious project is selected.

Is there a way to tie a Workspace to project, so I won't need to change it every time?

Answer (score 0):

No, workspace is completely independent of project.

You can have both projects mapped in the same workspace. That would remove the need to keep changing, but introduce some danger of cross checkin.

Comment: Are you sure this is possible? When creating workspace you need to specify local fodler: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/138960/how-to-map-tfs-to-two-local-directories
I still don't understand why VS cannot choose a workspace after loading   project which is usually mapped to specific workspace. It would make much more sense for me, maybe they will add it in the future versions.